# "¿Me lo puedo probar?" vs "¿Lo puedo probar?"

Tags: gramática, pronombres

¿Qué diferencia hay entre las oraciones siguientes?

1. ¿Me lo puedo probar?
2. ¿Lo puedo probar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formas equivalentes:

> 1. ¿Me lo puedo probar? = ¿Puedo probármelo?
> 2. ¿Lo puedo probar? = ¿Puedo probarlo?

El "**me**" (en cualquier forma) implica que el verbo "probar" está usado como [verbo pronominal](http://hispanoteca.eu/Gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Verbos%20pronominales%20comentados.htm) ("probar" -> "probarse"). La forma pronominal suele tener un sentido similar a la forma común (a veces no tanto), pero con un énfasis adicional referido a la persona/objeto nombrada. En este caso, "probar" es un simple verbo transitivo que sólo requiere un objeto directo, mientras que "probarse", además de eso, implica un objeto indirecto.

`[Yo] quiero probar esta comida.`  (comida=objeto directo ; "yo" soy el sujeto)

`[Yo] quiero probarme esta camisa.`  (camisa=objeto directo ; "yo" soy el sujeto y también -a través del 'me'- el objecto indirecto: **yo** quiero probar la camisa en **mi** persona)

Comment: Solo para información, pienso que Me es utilizado en raras ocasiones para expresar este tipo de cosas.

Answer (score 4):

A mi parecer, en la primera oración el `Me` implica un sentido de pertenencia que indica que lo que se va a probar va a ser en uno mismo.

Por ejemplo, podría referirse a un:

- Abrigo
- Sombrero
- Zapato
- Disfraz
- Cinturón, etc.

Mientras que la segunda oración es menos directa, e implica que lo que se va a probar no va a ser directamente en uno mismo.

Por ejemplo, podría referirse a un:

- Automóvil o algún otro vehículo
- Taco o algún otro artículo comestible
- Smartphone, etc.

Comment: +1 Pero, por favor, no omitas los acentos.

Comment: @leonbloy Gracias, tengo un teclado en inglés, por lo que es confuso usar los acentos, y olvide cambiar el corrector ortográfico a español :)